# how to source bashrc/bashprofile from python script

Tags: python, scripting, subprocess, bash

I am wondering how to source your bashrc from python. I automate turning scripts into aliases and whatnot. Here is what I see  in shell:

```
In [6]: subprocess.call(['sudo', 'source', '/home/cchilders/.bashrc'])
sudo: source: command not found
Out[6]: 1

In [7]: subprocess.call(['sudo', '.', '/home/cchilders/.bashrc'])
sudo: .: command not found
```

Thank you

Comment: `source` is a bash builtin, so you'd have to do `bash -c "source ..."`. However, that won't have the effect you're looking for since the shell settings are going to vanish when the bash process ends. You're gonig to need to do this *before* you launch python.

Comment: what if I call a shell script that just sources from within the python

Comment: this wont do what you want .... there is no way to call the rc and have it have any effect within the python shell or script .... what are you actually trying to accomplish? there maybe other ways to do it ...

Comment: @codyc4321, remember this: a child process *cannot* alter the environment of its parent process.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with that? Just running a bunch of shell commands in a subprocess isn't going to affect the state of the Python program (or any parent process for that matter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use subprocess.call, you're not using a shell - note from:
 https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call

`subprocess.call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False)`

the default for subprocess.call is no environment as you're not in a shell. Source is a bash builtin, so there's no program for subprocess to execute. And likely most of the code in your bashrc would be meaningless to call within the context of subprocess.

What you may want to do is provide more detailed information on what you're trying to accomplish by sourcing the bashrc file that can be done in a more pythonic way.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo source` wouldn't work because source is a shell built-in. I'm not sure of the technical reasons why you can't `sudo source`, as a `sudo echo` works just fine, but try using 
`subprocess.call(['.', '/home/cchilders/.bashrc'])` or whatever the equivalent would be.

Comment: or `type -a source` versus `type -a echo` -- that's why "sudo echo" works

Comment: I think you could do `subprocess.call("source /home/user/.bashrc",shell=True)` ... but as mentioned in the comments on OP this will not have the desired effect even if he manages to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import os

os.system("source /home/cchilders/.bashrc")
```

if you want to invoke any tools or run any other scripts:

```
os.system("source /home/cchilders/.bashrc && python3 script name")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `subprocess.run` and a subshell.

Instead of this:

```
subprocess.call(['sudo', 'source', '/home/cchilders/.bashrc'])
```

Try this:

```
subprocess.run("sudo bash -c 'source /home/cchilders/.bashrc'", shell=True)
```

Comment: `subprocess.run("bash -c 'source ~/.bashrc && {REST_OF_CMD}'")` worked for me when others didn't.